# Can I use HandshakeInterceptor With graphql-spring-boot-starter To Get Cookies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, graphql-java

I have a Spring Boot java app which serves up GraphQL subscriptions via graphql-spring-boot-starter.

I would like to access cookies in some fashion.

In other (not graphql) contexts, I've seen people use HandshakeInterceptor to get cookies before the websocket handshake.

I don't manually set up the websocket code, it is autowired via graphql-spring-boot-starter.  I see non-graphql examples of people overriding registerStompEndpoints on their websocket configuration, but in my case I don't have any explicit websocket configuration, it is auto created.

Is there a way I can wire a HandshakeInterceptor into graphql-spring-boot-starter's functionality? I already tried creating a HandshakeInterceptor bean, but that appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My setup was assuming some things about graphql-java that are no longer true. And I was not familiar with the websocket context.

The solution is to use GraphQLWebSocketContext, which provides HandshakeRequest, allows you to do:

```
graphQLWebSocketContext.getHandshakeRequest().getHeaders().get( "cookie" )
```